# Sending gzipped data over HTTPS

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, gzip

I need to send a gzipped byte array over HTTPS. I searched the web and only thing ı can found is SharpGIS.GZipWebClient.

However, the problem is - this third party solution only works with WebClient which allow you to send only String data.

(I'm on Windows Phone 8. Most of the WebClient methods do not exist.)

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Edit:

This is how I tried the POST JSON data over HTTPS using SharpGIS;

```
            WebClient webClient = new SharpGIS.GZipWebClient();
            webClient.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip";
            var uri = new Uri(pUrl, UriKind.Absolute);
            webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadStringCompleted);
            webClient.UploadStringTaskAsync(uri, jsonAsString);
```

But it doesn't compresses the string as well(as using OpenWriteSync method).

Comment: WebClient also allows you to write binary data: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144218(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: I'm terribly sorry that I forgot to mention I'm on Windows Phone 8. In Windows Phone 8 SDK, those methods are not included.

Comment: You're mistaken, the `OpenWriteAsync` method is included in Windows Phone 8 as well

Comment: Oh yeah! I messed up somehow. Thanks. But I have some other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You write the post data in the OpenWriteCompleted handler, like this:

```
void webClient_OpenWriteCompleted(object sender, OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   Stream s = e.Result;   
   s.Write(jsonAsByteArray, 0, jsonAsByteArray.Length);
   s.Flush();
   s.Close();
}
```

You should also add the appropriate error handling.

Comment: Yeah I see that but what I wanted to say is SharpGIS.GZipWebClient does not support OpenWrite... of WebClient as it's stated here; http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2011/05/29/GZIP-Compressed-Web-Requests-in-WP7.aspx

Comment: You should have a look at the NuGet packages for Visual Studio. There is a package for the newer HttpClient and also a Microsoft compression package. I think the compression package is still beta, but I would use it if I needed compression.